# Android - calcOpticalFlowPyrLK: assertion failed

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, opticalflow

I am tring to develop an optical flow method based on calcOpticalFlowPyrLK of OPENCV. I tried this code

```
 public Mat optical2(){

          Scalar red = new Scalar(255,0,0,255);

          if(mMOP2fptsPrev.rows() == 0) {

              Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, matOpFlowThis, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);

              matOpFlowThis.copyTo(matOpFlowPrev);

              Imgproc.goodFeaturesToTrack(matOpFlowPrev, MOPcorners, iGFFTMax, 0.05, 20);
              mMOP2fptsPrev.fromArray(MOPcorners.toArray());

              mMOP2fptsPrev.copyTo(mMOP2fptsSafe);
              }
          else
              {

              matOpFlowThis.copyTo(matOpFlowPrev);

              Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, matOpFlowThis, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);

              Imgproc.goodFeaturesToTrack(matOpFlowThis, MOPcorners, iGFFTMax, 0.05, 20);
              mMOP2fptsThis.fromArray(MOPcorners.toArray());

              mMOP2fptsSafe.copyTo(mMOP2fptsPrev);

              mMOP2fptsThis.copyTo(mMOP2fptsSafe);
              }

          Video.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(matOpFlowPrev, matOpFlowThis, mMOP2fptsPrev, mMOP2fptsThis, mMOBStatus, mMOFerr);

          cornersPrev = mMOP2fptsPrev.toList();
          cornersThis = mMOP2fptsThis.toList();
          byteStatus = mMOBStatus.toList();
          y = byteStatus.size() - 1;
          for (x = 0; x < y; x++) {
              if (byteStatus.get(x) == 1) {
                  pt = cornersThis.get(x);
                  pt2 = cornersPrev.get(x);
                  Core.circle(mRgba, pt, 5, red, iLineThickness - 1);    
                  Core.line(mRgba, pt, pt2, red, iLineThickness);
                  }
              }

        return mRgba;
      }
```

But I Found this error:

> 04-03 13:19:35.170: E/cv::error()(17831): OpenCV Error: Assertion
>   failed ((npoints = prevPtsMat.checkVector(2, CV_32F, true)) >= 0) in
>   void cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray,
>   cv::InputArray, cv::InputOutputArray, cv::OutputArray,
>   cv::OutputArray, cv::Size, int, cv::TermCriteria, int, double), file
>   /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/video/src/lkpyramid.cpp,
>   line 845 04-03 13:19:35.170: E/org.opencv.video(17831):
>   video::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK_12() caught cv::Exception:
>   /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/video/src/lkpyramid.cpp:845:
>   error: (-215) (npoints = prevPtsMat.checkVector(2, CV_32F, true)) >= 0
>   in function void cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(cv::InputArray,
>   cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, cv::InputOutputArray, cv::OutputArray,
>   cv::OutputArray, cv::Size, int, cv::TermCriteria, int, double) 04-03
>   13:19:35.170: W/dalvikvm(17831): threadid=11: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x40f19930) 04-03 13:19:35.170:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17831): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-12741 04-03
>   13:19:35.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17831): CvException
>   [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception:
>   /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/video/src/lkpyramid.cpp:845:
>   error: (-215) (npoints = prevPtsMat.checkVector(2, CV_32F, true)) >= 0
>   in function void cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(cv::InputArray,
>   cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, cv::InputOutputArray, cv::OutputArray,
>   cv::OutputArray, cv::Size, int, cv::TermCriteria, int, double) 04-03
>   13:19:35.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17831): ] 04-03 13:19:35.170:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17831):  at
>   org.opencv.video.Video.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK_2(Native Method) 04-03
>   13:19:35.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17831):    at
>   org.opencv.video.Video.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(Video.java:501) 04-03
>   13:19:35.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17831):    at
>   org.opencv.samples.facedetect.FdActivity.optical2(FdActivity.java:374)
>   04-03 13:19:35.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17831):  at
>   org.opencv.samples.facedetect.FdActivity.onCameraFrame(FdActivity.java:305)
>   04-03 13:19:35.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17831):  at
>   org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.deliverAndDrawFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:387)
>   04-03 13:19:35.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17831):  at
>   org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView$CameraWorker.run(JavaCameraView.java:328)
>   04-03 13:19:35.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17831):  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

Can you help me ?

Comment: in my case, I was running from python and the array of previous points didn't have the right data type. the error went away as soon as I casted them to float32.

Comment: i also tried to convert mMOP2fptsThis.convertTo(mMOP2fptsThis, CvType.CV_32F); but it didnt worked with this also